# Change custom properties IBM Liberty 20x

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

How can we define and change custom propeties values in IBM liberty , When migrated from WAS to liberty, below properties in WAS (Web Container Settings > Web container > Custom
properties > New) has to be changed in Liberty:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.initFilterBeforeInitServlet = false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFilterInitAtStartup = false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.mapFiltersToAsterisk = false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.enabledefaultservletrequestpathelements = false
```

What are the equivalent properties in Liberty?

Error:

```
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.emc.xcp.ui.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:26) [Services-21.2.0000.0030.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.emc.xcp.ui.web.filter.CustomCharEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomCharEncodingFilter.java:43) [Services-21.2.0000.0030.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.emc.xcp.ui.RestCorsFilter.doFilterInternal(RestCorsFilter.java:49) [Services-21.2.0000.0030.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:304) [ziplet-2.1.2.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.emc.xcp.ui.CompressingFilterProxy.doFilter(CompressingFilterProxy.java:38) [Services-21.2.0000.0030.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:56) [com.ibm.ws.security.jaspic.1.1_1.0.47.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.  One of these is available as a configuration attribute of the [`<webcontainer>`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_webContainer.html) element. In server.xml,

```
  <webcontainer invokeFilterInitAtStartup="false">
```